# SQL "In" Statement Match Anything

Tags: sql, subquery

If I have a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN ({SUBS})
```

Is there anything I can replace {SUBS} with that will return all rows in the table?

Further details:

I am building the SQL dynamically in my app, so I cannot (should not) edit other parts of the query except what's in braces. So,

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

will not do.

Also,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table1)
```

would be hackish and highly inefficient. Consider the table have more than 50k rows.

Comment: I know this isn't the question, but I have to ask: are you just trying to get all of the rows? If so, just take off the "WHERE col1 IN ({SUBS})" part.

Comment: someone told me once - there's no such thing as a stupid question...

Comment: sounds like someone is building dynamic sql to me...

Comment: "...would be highly inefficient. Consider the table have more than 50k rows." You said you wanted to retrieve all 50k rows. I think efficiency's kind of a moot point.

Comment: The question is, what is the [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(mathematics)) with respect to [semijoin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033748/what-kind-of-join-do-i-need/7036894#7036894) in SQL? A good question which you answer yourself with your last query!

Answer (score 5):

This would do it:

```
select col1 from table1
```

**Edit:** There seems to be a bit of confusion - the OP asked what value could be used to replace `{SUBS}` that would return all rows from `table1`.  My answer above is what you could use in place of `{SUBS}` that would return all the rows.

Comment: you mean **select * from table1**

Comment: Nope, I meant `select col1 from table1` :)

Comment: I think viligant is trying to find out if someone could use SQL injection to find all the data in the table, which Andrew's reply would allow, although I might use

SELECT distinct col1 FROM table1

But his answer is proper

Comment: From the posted question, it appears vigilant is trying to get full rows, not just col1.

Comment: @pstanton, @Donnie DeBoer: the answer is just the part to put in place of the .. the IN (...)

Comment: @Donnie DeBoer - Andrew meant replace {SUBS} with "select col1 from table1"

Comment: @Donnie DeBoer and @pstanton, what Andrew Hare means is that your should replace `{SUBS}` in the OP's question, with the SQL he posted in his answer which would result in getting all columns, not just `col1`. See my answer for an elaboration.

Comment: @Sparky: I don't think the use of `DISTINCT` would be any more efficient. The query plan would in any case remove duplicates if deemed beneficial. Using `DISTINCT` essentially forces the query plan to always remove duplicates - even when not beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN (COLUMN_NAME)
```

Have you tried just using **COL1** for **{SUBS}**?

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN (col1)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you replaced `{SUBS}` with `SELECT col1 FROM table1`, you would end up with

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table1);
```

which would return all rows from `table1`. This is, of course, simply a more roundabout way of saying:

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table1)
```

does work, but is highly inefficient; requiring a merge join to return all rows.

Use the following which is just as efficient as regular `SELECT * FROM table1`

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN (col1)
```

However, that said; I suggest you have a chat to the person who is trying to impose the `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN ({SUBS})` structure. There is no **good** reason to do so.

- It unnecessarily complicates queries.
- Creates risk of highly inefficient queries.
- Potentially even limits developers to use certain techniques.

I suspect the person imposing this is trying to implement some sort of *silver-bullet* framework. Remember, the **golden rule** in software development is that there are **no** *silver-bullets*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to retrieve every row in the table, then:

```
select * from table1
```

If you're trying to prove a point or win a bet or something, then:

```
select * from table1 where col1 in (select col1 from table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query requires some WHERE condition, then I would try to replace it with an EXISTS statement:

```
select
  *
from
  table1 t1
where
  exists ( {subs} )
```

Then {subs} can be replaced with any expression that does not yield NULL.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Oracle:

```
select * from table1 where col1 in (col1)
```