# What kind of join do I need?

Tags: sql, semi-join

I have a votes table:

```
 votes
-----------------
 userid   gameid
-------  --------
   a        1
   a        2
   a        3
   b        1
   b        2
```

and a games table:

```
 games
----------------
 gameid   title
 ------   ------
    1       foo
    2       bar
    3       fizz
    4       buzz
```

What kind of a join would I use to perform the query "Select * from games where [user A voted on the game]"?

I've tried following [Jeff's guide](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html), but I'm not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use an `INNER` join to establish the relationship between the common `gameid` field;

```
select
  votes.userid,
  games.title
from games
  inner join votes on (votes.gameid = game.gameid)
where
  votes.userid = 'a'
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I was definitely doing my "on" clause wrong, which I think was my first problem. Inner Join makes sense, because I don't want any records that don't match in both.

Answer (score 1):

This gets you the games with a vote:

```
SELECT
   g.title
   v.userid
FROM
   games g

   INNER JOIN votes v
   ON g.gameid = v.gameid
```

This gets you all of the games, even if not voted on:

```
SELECT
   g.title
   v.userid
FROM
   games g

   LEFT JOIN votes v
   ON g.gameid = v.gameid
```

Comment: Good answer, given the ambiguous question.

Answer (score 1):

The relational operator you require is [semijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29).

Most SQL products lacks an explicit semijoin operator or keyword. Standard SQL-92 has a `MATCH (subquery)` predicate but is not widely implemented (the truly relational language [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28data_language_specification%29) uses the keyword the `MATCHING` for its semijoin operator).

A semijoin can of course be written using other SQL predicates. The most commonly seen use `EXISTS` or `IN (subquery)`.

Depending on the data it may be possible to use `SELECT DISTINCT..INNER JOIN`. However, in your case you are using `SELECT * FROM ...` and an `INNER JOIN` will project over the votes table resulting in `userid` being appended to the column list along with a duplicate column for `gameid` (if your SQL product of choice supports it, using `NATURAL JOIN` would solve the duplicate column problem and mean you would omit the `ON` clause too).

Using `INTERSECT` is another possible approach if your SQL product supports it and again depending on the data (specifically, when the headings of the two tables are the same)>

Personally, I prefer to use `EXISTS` in SQL for semijoin because the join clauses are closer together in the written code and doesn't result in projection over the joined table e.g.

```
SELECT *
  FROM games
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM votes AS v
                WHERE v.gameid = games.gameid
                      AND v.userid = 'a'
              );
```

Comment: This is interesting. It achieves the same thing as the Inner Join, but without returning the values from the votes table. Is there any significant performance difference?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, given your limited description, the following would get you a list of games where user A voted on the game:

```
select g.gameid, g.title
from games g
inner join votes v
on v.gameid = g.gameid
where v.userid = 'a'
```