# SQL Inner join in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join

I am facing problem with Inner join in Access Database. I have two table having two column each. one is MID and other is DOB in both table. The name of first table is maintable and other is under5. I want to retrieve all those records that are present in under5 table after matching it with maintable so i used Inner join. the problem is there is a MID 10106 whose frequency in under5 table is 2 and in maintable it is 5 but after running the query the number of MID(10106) returned is 10( i guess the expected behaviour should be 2) which is really absurd. please help me to solve this problem. 
This is my Query:

```
SELECT maintable.MID, maintable.DOB, Under5.MID, Under5.DOB
FROM under5
INNER JOIN maintable ON under5.MID=maintable.MID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is abosolutely fine.

Every row in Main Table will be matched with Every Row in inner table. As there are 5 rows in Main Table And two rows in inner table 5*2 = 10 rows

```
Can there be any other way so that i could only retrieve those MID and DOB 
that is present in under5 table after matching it with maintable.
```

try this

```
SELECT distinct Under5.MID, Under5.DOB 
FROM under5, MainTable
where under5.mid = mainTable.mid
```

Comment: Can there be any other way so that i could only retrieve those MID and DOB that is present in under5 table after matching it with maintable.

Comment: Can there be any other way so that i could only retrieve those MID and DOB that is present in under5 table after matching it with maintable.

Comment: I tried Distinct clause but ended with the same problem. don't know why access is behaving this way

Comment: @user510686 please see edited answer above and see if it works ?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a [semijoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033748/what-kind-of-join-do-i-need/7036894#7036894) e.g. try:

```
SELECT Under5.MID, Under5.DOB
  FROM under5
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM maintable 
                WHERE maintable.MID = under5.MID
              );
```