# How make a select with "repeated" condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, windows

I have the following select that need to be done:

> select top 1 a, b, c, d from Products where
>   CodDep = 10 or
>   CodDep = 11 or
>   CodDep = 12 or 
>   CodDep = 13 or
>   CodDep = 26 or
>   CodDep = 27 or 
>   CodDep = 32 or
>   CodDep = 34 or
>   CodDep = 248442 or
>   CodDep = 259741
>   order by LastUpdate

Is there an easy way to do this without all this repetition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select top 1 
  a, b, c, d 
from 
  Products 
where
  CodDep IN (10,12,12,13,26,27,32,34,248442,259741)
order by 
  LastUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a, b, c, d FROM Products WHERE
CodDep IN (10,11,12,13,26,27,32,34,248442,259741) ORDER BY LastUpdate
```

Comment: I dont think there is Limit keyword in SQLServer. I am guess sql sever because of Top keyword in original query.

Comment: OK. I havn't assumed SQL server. I have changed answer. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

SQL has but one data structure: the table. Put the values in a table and [semi join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033748/what-kind-of-join-do-i-need/7036894#7036894) to that table e.g.

```
WITH Params
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (10), (11), (12), (13),
                     (26), (27), (32), (34), 
                     (248442), (259741)
             ) AS T (CodDep)
     )
SELECT TOP 1 a, b, c, d 
  FROM Products 
 WHERE CodDep IN (SELECT CodDep FROM Params)
 ORDER 
    BY LastUpdate;
```