# Is there some way to select the first table without writing all the fields names in the query?

Tags: sql, select, join, informix

Q: If I have ***two tables*** joined together, and I want to get `(*)` from the first table, I mean all the fields of the first table.

Shall I write all the fields names of the first table in the query? Or is there some way to select * just from the first table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not to list all the fields, see the example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
from T1
join t2 on condition
```

Comment: Consider adding the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: @onedaywhen yep, thanx. And surely better use EXISTS instead of JOIN

Answer (score 3):

`first_table.*` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds more like a [semi join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033748/what-kind-of-join-do-i-need/7036894#7036894). Consider rewriting e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*
  FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.id;
```

can be re-written as

```
SELECT *
  FROM T1
 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM T2);
```