# SQL Need help joining tables

Tags: sql, join

I have a select SQL query which is really big and it should be pulling in about 5000 records. But when I use the JOIN It cuts the number of records to say 1000 because it only shows records where a value exists on the joined value, how would I go about pulling all records no matter whether the Join finds that a value exists or NOT?

Comment: You want to use an outer join. There's a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join

Comment: It could be that you need a [semi-join](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7036894/15354). There are a number of ways of implementing this; if you do go with outer join then add the DISTINCT keyword to the SELECT clause (assuming it is not already present) otherwise you may experience the number of rows in the result **increasing**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left outer join : [MSDN Outer Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx)

Comment: This was what I tried, only realised it was correct because I thought it was giving other values in the other table but it was just my hidden records. I knew it was a noob question!. I'm rewarding answer to you because you look like first in

Comment: Don't forget to add the `DISTINCT` keyword to the `SELECT` clause (assuming it is not already present) otherwise you may experience the number of rows in the result **increasing**!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing an inner join, perform a left outer join